# jQuery ajax call returning null json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(a, b, c) { 
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        console.log($.parseJSON(c.responseText));
    }
});
```

- a is null.
- b is "success".
- c is a big object.
- and the parsing of c.responseText results in the a valid object.

Now... why is "a" empty? Shouldn't it be the same as the call to $.parseJSON(c.responseText)?

The response is a 200-status, application/json content-type, JSON string:

```
{
"Request":{
   "Action":"ShowPageBasedOverview",
   "ArgsString":"1",
   "Args":["1"]
},
"Result":"<div><strong>html stuff</strong> 1,369,110</div>",
"Status":"Ok"
}
```

Comment: What version of jquery and what browser are you using? Is the outcome the same in all browsers? Very interesting problem. Are you using any plugins that modify $.ajax? any plugins at all?

Comment: Looks like this is running on jQuery 1.8.0
Chrome is broken. Checking other browsers now.
No other plugins that modify this.

Comment: I don't see any relevant bug reports to this issue (and i have not come across this myself in my own ajax applications.) Are you using any form validation or file upload plugins? I think something might be overriding `$.ajax`

Comment: Form validation is done through the .NET validation controls. There's also the following scripts added:

jquery.easing.1.3.js, ui.datepicker.js, jquery.fancybox-1.2.0.pack.js.... and ckediter, rangy-core and some custom JS files.